# Where can I find numeric maps of aerodromes?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport

I desperately need a map of an airport aerodrome like the ones used for tracking the movements of aircraft similar to the picture below and I don't know where I can find these ones :
[image]

Comment: You should try to explain what you plan on using this map for, then it will be more clear to people exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Airport Diagrams such as this one of [KPNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Philadelphia_Airport)

[image]

are published [here on the FAA website](http://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/diagrams/) as well as in [in the airport facilities directory](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/). These are up to date and considered legal for navigation as far as I know. If you are looking for them in another type of format that may be tough, you can try reaching out to the specific airports or the FAA directly.

Comment: These are also in the Canadian flight supplements. :)

Comment: Well I asked the airport for it and they don't have one just the pdf format !

Answer (score 3):

[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=14/32.8997/-97.0256) is a good place to start.

I've used it for a project with real aircraft data and found that the OSM map of the airport I was interested in had a small offset. Using [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM) I was able to correct for the offset and add missing taxiways and additional features.

I have also tried to use PDF based airport diagrams from various Aeronautical Information Publications (AIP) but I was not successful in extracting the specific elements I was interested in.

Comment: I saw the osm map and it seems correct not needing modifications I just have to change the colors of the map and it looks difficult!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, what are you building?

Comment: I wanna simulate the traffic of aircraft on the aerodrome that's why I need the map so I can project the airplanes on .

Comment: I think OSM support map styles in some form of [CSS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stylesheets). Perhaps that would help you. Note that airport surfaces have key value pairs in their XML definition like this: `<tag k="aeroway" v="apron"/>`

Comment: okey! I'll check that thank you.